# UIPopover Not Showing View Inside

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview, uipopovercontroller

I'm using a popover that should simply show a UIView inside. But although the popup shows up, it contains only an empty view (that is colored in some kind of dark blue).
The UIViewController is use is the "PreferencesController" in there.

My Code to open the popup is the following:

```
- (IBAction)showPopup:(id)sender {

if (_preferencesController == nil) {
    self.preferencesController = [[PreferencesController alloc]init];
    self.preferencesControllerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                initWithContentViewController:_preferencesController];
}
[self.preferencesControllerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Besides that I only have the "**preferencesController**" that doesn't include any special methods besides the `viewDidLoad` with "`self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(800.0, 800.0);`"

This is what I get:
[image: Popup]

Any ideas why it isn't working properly?

Comment: when the popover shows, is the popover arrow showing properly (it appears and it is pointing at the correct barbuttonitem)?

Comment: @PedroCattori: when we write like `permittedArrowDirections:0` there will be no arrow for the popover.

Comment: in that case, temporarily setting a `permittedArrowDirection` might be useful for debugging, as you will be able to see if the arrow is pointing to the barbuttonitem, and thus if the bug comes from having an invalid barbuttonitem parameter or not. (i assume the barbuttonitem is only used for positioning the popover and drawing its arrow. is this not the case?)

Comment: Actually first I had the permittedArrowDirection activated, and it's pointing correctly to the barbuttonitem. I just used :0 for a better look.
And I also had a smaller size first, but it wasn't working either.
I just increase the size to 800.0 because I created a UIIVewController with the Storyboard to create two labels on it. But I also linked the UIViewController with my PreferencesController, with is a UIViewController. So that can't be the problem either... :/

Comment: I just added a picture of the popup shown, maybe that gives you some hint where the problem may lie.

Answer (score 2):

## Possible Problem

800.0 width is too large for a Popover to handle.

---

In the [documentation for UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

(Discussing `contentSizeForViewInPopover`)

> This property contains the desired size for the view controller when it is displayed in a popover. By default, the width is set to 320 points and the height is set to 1100 points. You can change these values as needed.
>
> The recommended width for popovers is 320 points. If needed, you can return a **width value as large as 600 points**, but doing so is not recommended.

---

### Possible Solution

Try presenting your UIViewController modally by calling `presentModalViewController:animated:` from the UIViewController you want the modal view controller to animate on top of.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code makes the issue:

```
[self.preferencesControllerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

Because sender is of type id, so you need to cast it, Like:

```
UIBarButtonItem *but = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
 [self.preferencesControllerPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:but permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

Hope it'll solve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't changed anything